# Get values with Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String in javascript

```
"guardar.periodoLaboral.personal.vital{0}{1}.presentado"
```

I need extract "0" and "1" (This values are variables in the string).

How extract this with regex?

Update: I tried.

```
var a ="guardar.periodoLaboral.personal.vital{1}{0}.presentado"
var expresion=/([0-9]+)/ig;
var values=a.match(expresion);
console.log(values);
//This return 0 and 1 as I need
```

but I need only the values within "{" and "}" because the string "guardar.periodoLaboral.personal.vital{1}{0}.presentado10" returns 1,0,10.

I new in javascript regex.

Comment: Writing code would be a good start, or learning regexes...

Comment: Regex operates on non-ambiguous parsing. You need to have some idea of the format that {0} and {1} will be in to decide on a good regex. Can you give us that information? Will they be things like `.eso` (starting with a period as part of the path)?

Also, like Marc said, you should show us code that you have tried.

Comment: ... try it yourself first... and then if you have some problem, ask. BUT TRY FIRST!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript Replace method along with the regex that matches what you are looking for to strip it out. Then assign it to a variable.

```
var testString = "guardar.periodoLaboral.personal.vital{0}{1}.presentado";
var donish = testString.replace(/({.})/g,''); 
console.log( donish );
```

Returns this "guardar.periodoLaboral.personal.vital.presentado"

I use this sito test and create my Regex. [enter link description here](https://regex101.com/#javascript)
and this is the documentation for the JavaScript replace method [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)